# Access key not appearing in headers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following request, but the accessKey doesn't appear in the headers? Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
       'accessKey': 'key123'
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        callback.call(null, xhr.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm executing your code and it does send "accesskey" header (i'm using chrome). I suggest you to use "X-Access-Key" for crossbrowsing improvement.

Comment: Really? How are you executing it? how would I use X-Access-Key?

Comment: Just replace `accessKey` by `X-Access-Key`, i mean, you should use `X-` prefix for custom HTTP headers. You could also use `X-accessKey`.